# Manipulation with GIS content on the web using the WebGL

Tags: maps, gis, webgl

I have task to create program for manipulation with 3d content on the web. When I said 3d content i mean
on 3d map (witch i have and it is something like *.sdm) which i should load into browser and work some basic operation with it (rotate screen, change camera etc...).

Because i am totaly n00b i want to ask a couple of questions:
 1. How to load maps into browser. Just for notice that my map have sdm extension. Is this possible?
 2. What i should use for represent 3d content. I am thinking of GLGE framework for webGL, if it is possible of course

What should be the most painless and the most effective way to do this? Maybe i was totally wrong when choose webGL?

Answer (score 1):

Programs that use WebGL aren't mature enough to do what you want. Within the next few years, when GIS applications start popping up it may be possible, but not now.

Also, keep in mind that WebGL is what gives you access to a low-level graphics library. It does not directly have anything to do with GIS data.

You may want to take a look at OpenLayers (2d, javascript based) or WorldWind-Java (3d, jogl/java based). Both of these programs can display map information in a browser.

http://openlayers.org/

http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/